# Opening MS-Excel 2010 from MS-PROJECT 2016 through VBA

Tags: excel, ms-project, vba

I had developed a VBA macro in MS Project 2010 that opens MS Excel 2010 workbook using

`Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application").`

On upgrading to MS-Project 2016 but still using Excel 2010, the macro now stops on that statement giving

> Run time error: Automation Error - Library not registered

Changing the command to `"Set appExcel = New Excel.Application"` returns the same error.

Comment: It sounds like an issue of references to multiple versions of Excel in the registry. [social.msdn...](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d35f6852-8770-4503-8428-4a7040b654cd/suddenly-automation-error-library-not-registered?forum=isvvba)

Answer (score 0):

I agree. Define appExcel as Object with no reference and it works. Define as Excel.Application with a reference to an installed version of Excel and it works.

Select Tools, References in the VBE and check your refrences. If not clear post back screenshot and more of your code (EG the Dim statements)

Answer (score 0):

As Rod & Rachel have indicated - use late binding so the version of Excel isn't an issue.

I just have a .bas file that I drag into the projects that need it:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim oXL As Object
    Dim oWB As Object
    Dim oWS As Object

    Set oXL = CreateXL
    Set oWB = oXL.WorkBooks.Add
    Set oWS = oWB.WorkSheets.Add

End Sub

Public Function CreateXL(Optional bVisible As Boolean = True) As Object

    Dim oTmpXL As Object

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Defer error trapping in case Excel is not running. '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oTmpXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'If an error occurs then create an instance of Excel. '
    'Reinstate error handling.                            '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER
        Set oTmpXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If

    oTmpXL.Visible = bVisible
    Set CreateXL = oTmpXL

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure CreateXL."
            Err.Clear
    End Select

End Function
```

**Note:**  Using this means you don't have access to intellisense and any constants will need their numerical value entered instead - e.g. `xlUp` will have to be entered as `-4162`.  To find these values just open Excel and in the VBE immediate window type `?xlUp.`